# HTTP1 + TLS to HTTP2

Tags: reverse-proxy, http2, http-1.1

I'm looking for a technical solution that can convert http1.1 + TLS1.2 requests to http2 (h2 or h2c).

I have to integrate a custom web server that only supports http2 (i can't modify the source code).

I've already search on nginx reverse proxy but it does not supports http2_proxy_pass. I'm now reading the documentation of the ha proxy

I could also do a custom piece of code that deserialize/reserialize package

What would the best / more stable solution ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looking for similar approach, have you find them?